# How to find the mean of words using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am new to R and I'm trying to scrape data from a website which contains book listings. I have managed to scrape the 20 book names from the website, I now want to find the average word length for book names on this website (The mean of all word lengths). However I am not sure how to do this using the R programming language.

Code so far:

```
url <- 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'

bookNames <- read_html(allUrls) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " "), concat( " ", "product_pod", ""))]//a') %>%
  html_text
view(bookNames)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `word_vec <- c("Hello", "World"); mean(stringr::str_length(word_vec))`

Comment: If you've already scraped the data, then you likely don't need to include the URL scraping in your question; it would likely be easier (for us) if you provided at least a sample of the data provided by that scraping. The text on the top of all [tag:r]-tag pages suggests using `dput()` to provide sample data, as it is unambiguous (data output on the console can often *not* be what you think it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(books, nchar) %>%
    flatten_int %>%
     mean
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can put all your words in a list, call it 'books'. Then:

```
values<-lapply(books,nchar)
```

and finally:

```
mean(unlist(values))
```